Do other countries besides Ukraine have this policy that people of an age when they typically don't have children can't be mobilized?
Al-Jazeera says:

Population loss is one of the reasons why Ukrainian President Volodymyr Zelenskyy has refused to mobilise men aged 18-25, as most of them have not had children yet, according to Ukrainian officials. The eligible age range for Ukraine’s military is 25 to 60.

Do [any] other countries have similar policies?

I edited out the [tag:mobilization] tag and added the pre-existing [tag:conscription] tag. In theory, mobilization can refer to preparation, readiness or deployment of existing soldiers, but in the context of the article, it evidently refers to a draft, or lack thereof, in this case, so there may be no need to create a  new tag when the existing one works.

@Obie2.0: Good call. It turns out that in Ukraine, unlike in Russia, conscription also doesn't begin until age 25. While Russia makes a difference between conscripting and sending sending people to the front, it seems Ukraine does not, for now anyway.

Is that true? Did they really only conscript 25+ y.o. aged men for their ATO and for the military service in general before 2022?

@alamar: IDK how it was some years go, but now https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-war-conscription-mobilization-251058a942a253f3eaec2c53373adf03

@Obie2.0 During a war like this, they're probably conflated since they they can't get enough troops without drafting, and everyone who is drafted will be mobilized.

The reasoning seems unusual. According to this source https://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2017/08/31/547320586/fatherhood-after-forty-its-now-a-lot-more-common-study-finds, the average age of new fathers in the US is >30. The discrepancy with the 18-25 range seems pretty large.

Would Israel count? They don’t draft married women, which is often used as a loophole.

@JonathanReez: interesting. OTOH not that many countries draft women to begin with, AFAIK.

Generally speaking most countries favor drafting the youngest soldiers possible, past 18.  There are a number of reasons for that, including fitness, willingness to follow orders and... well getting it out of the way before they are integrated professionally.  So it does seem unusual, but there are demographic concerns driving that, I believe.  As well as political ones.

Very unusual. The U.S. selective service is only for men 18-26, so virtually no overlap with Ukraine's age range.

No, I don't think this is common at all.  Historically, most countries liked to draft men as soon as they were past 18, with deferments for secondary education.
Reasons probably include:

physical fitness

easier to get to follow orders, and less instinct of self-preservation

doesn't interfere as much with their labor force participation.


Forces News - Which countries still have conscription?
World Population Review - Countries with Mandatory Military Service 2024
France used to be 18-35.  Germany 18.
Notice how frequently "18" is the lower bound and that the upper bound, when given, is quite low, by Ukrainian standards.
According to War on the Rocks, this is partly due to politics and partly because Ukraine has a narrow "chokepoint" on the 18-25 year old demographic pyramid.
